# Why would you want to ignore reversed graphics?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I reversed some buttons because I liked the way the images on them fit into the scene better in that position. However, when I reversed the buttons they were no longer clickable. I unchecked "ignore reversed graphics" on the canvas and now it works again. I just want to make sure that this won't be an issue down the line so can you please tell me in which scenarios would you WANT to ignore reversed graphics? When would this be useful?

Thanks,

Comment: What exactly do you mean by reversed? Like pointing away from the user? Why not rather only flip the texture you are using on it? In general: Yes you usually do not want to interact with UI from behind ... happening especially if your UI is in World space ... Imagine e.g. HoloLens -> you pin a UI to a rooms wall .. go into the next room and suddenly interact with UI on the other side of a wall ;)

Answer (score 0):

From what I've observed, let's say for instance you are using a graphics raycaster of some sort.

Perhaps if your graphic is reversed, it would be facing away from the raycaster?

You would probably want to ignore it in this case unless it is facing towards the raycast.